# MapReduce.SDK: How to wait for MapReduce job?

Tags: c#, hadoop, mapreduce, azure-hdinsight, cortana-intelligence

I'm using the Microsoft MapReduce SDK to start a Mapper only job.

The call to `hadoop.MapReduceJob.ExecuteJob` is throwing a "Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (not found)" exception immediately.

When inspecting the HDInsight Query Console the job successfully starts and finishes later. It also writes proper output files.

My guess is, ExecuteJob is trying to access output data before the job has finished.

What is the correct way to handle this situation?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.HDInsight;
using Microsoft.Hadoop.MapReduce;
using AzureAnalyzer.MultiAnalyzer;

namespace AzureAnalyzer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IHadoop hadoop = Hadoop.Connect(Constants.azureClusterUri, Constants.clusterUser,
            Constants.hadoopUser, Constants.clusterPassword, Constants.storageAccount,
            Constants.storageAccountKey, Constants.container, true);

            try {
                var output = hadoop.MapReduceJob.ExecuteJob<MultiAnalyzerJob>();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nException: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got another way to do the same thing but takes a bit of effort since it requires the mapper and reducer files to be transferred to the hadoop cluster storage.

you need to add Microsoft.Hadoop.Client then Microsoft Azure HDInsight NuGet package as well.

```
var jobcred = new BasicAuthCredential();
        jobcred.UserName = "clusteruserid";
        jobcred.Password = "clusterpassword";
        jobcred.Server = new Uri("https://clusterurl");

 StreamingMapReduceJobCreateParameters jobpara = new StreamingMapReduceJobCreateParameters()
        {
            JobName="mapreduce",
            Mapper = "Mapper.exe",
            Reducer = "Reducer.exe",
            Input= "wasb:///mydata/input",
            Output = "wasb:///mydata/Output",
            StatusFolder= "wasb:///mydata/sOutput"

        };
        jobpara.Files.Add("wasb:///mydata/Mapper.exe");
        jobpara.Files.Add("wasb:///mydata/Reducer.exe");


 // Create a Hadoop client to connect to HDInsight.
        var jobClient = JobSubmissionClientFactory.Connect(jobcred);


        // Run the MapReduce job.
        JobCreationResults mrJobResults = jobClient.CreateStreamingJob(jobpara);


        // Wait for the job to complete.
        Console.Write("Job running...");
        JobDetails jobInProgress = jobClient.GetJob(mrJobResults.JobId);
        while (jobInProgress.StatusCode != JobStatusCode.Completed
          && jobInProgress.StatusCode != JobStatusCode.Failed)
        {
            Console.Write(".");
            jobInProgress = jobClient.GetJob(jobInProgress.JobId);
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        }
        // Job is complete.
        Console.WriteLine("!");
        Console.WriteLine("Job complete!");
        Console.WriteLine("Press a key to end.");
        Console.Read();
```

Hope this helps. I was able to run jobs without throwing any exceptions.

this in fact waits for the job to be complete.

Comment: Thank you very much. Finally something that worked!!

Answer (score 0):

Please verify if all required services to run the program are up and running. The 404 error indicates that some URL the program tries to access internally is not accessible.

Comment: Could you point me to any resource explaining, what services need to run and how I can verify them?

Comment: This link is a good reference. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hadoop-emulator-get-started/ Hope you know these services.

Comment: Yeah, those service run all the time. Maybe I should have mentioned I'm running the mapper in Azure, not on the emulator. I doubt these services are necessary in this case.